# Is there a Listener that will return when the phone GPS enters a certain longitude or latitude area

Tags: android, latitude-longitude

Does the Android SDK have a Listener that will return when the phone GPS enters a certain longitude or latitude area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There is a function called [addProximityAlert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#)

Document says:

> It sets a proximity alert for the location given by the position (latitude,
>   longitude) and the given radius.
>
> When the device detects that it has entered or exited the area surrounding the 
>   location, the given PendingIntent will be used to create an Intent to be fired.
>
> The fired Intent will have a boolean extra added with key 
>   KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING. If the value is true, the device is entering the 
>   proximity region; if false, it is exiting.
>
> Due to the approximate nature of position estimation, if the device passes 
>   through the given area briefly, it is possible that no Intent will be fired.
>   Similarly, an Intent could be fired if the device passes very close to the 
>   given area but does not actually enter it.
>
> After the number of milliseconds given by the expiration parameter, the location 
>   manager will delete this proximity alert and no longer monitor it. A value of -1 
>   indicates that there should be no expiration time.